# How do I write a HQL Query for this?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want a single HQL query that returns all groups containing a given user that where created before a given date. Somehow I can't get it right.

```
public class Group
{
    @ManyToMany
    Set<User> users;
    Date created;
}

public class User
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

II-Bhima's answer is essentially right - here is a little fix:

```
select g from Group as g
inner join g.users as user
where g.created < :createdDate
and user = :user
```

you need it so that Groups are returned and not Object[] with Group-User 2-tuples.